# Transfer files from Ubuntu Server to Windows

Tags: windows, backup, ubuntu-server

I have a **webpage in a Ubuntu Server**, and I use ssh to connect to it. Now I'm looking for a solution to transfer files (indeed, to transfer the backups generated there automatically) **to my Windows computer**.

I have read about DeltaCopy, or rsync, but I don't know how to use it exactly. I need something to work **with Windows and Ubuntu Server at same time**, because I want to "download" backups generated at Ubuntu Server to my Windows hard disk drive.

We are talking about at least 150GB, and would be nice to create a connection so I can perform this operation as many times as I need. Do you have any solution? Also appreciate an explanation of how to use it :)

Answer (score 4):

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) or `pscp` (comes with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) are all fine options, since SSH servers usually have the `sftp` subsystem preconfigured.

Other file managers come with sftp/scp connectivity as well, such as SpeedCommander.

Given the amount of data you want to copy, `rsync` is probably the best option, however. It uses rolling hashes and can therefore **resume a previously interrupted transfer** easily and efficiently (not transferring anything more than needed). Raw `scp` isn't so efficient.

`rsync`, when told so, will transparently set up an SSH tunnel and that tunnel will be used to transfer the data. This is as easy as saying `--rsh=ssh` on the `rsync` command line. However, assuming you are on Windows, there won't be any `ssh` binary around under normal circumstances. So that would fail. You can therefore use `plink.exe` from the PuTTY package (see link above) to help you out. Say: `-e "C:\putty\plink.exe -l ssh-username"` (where you replace `ssh-username` and `C:\putty\plink.exe` with values matching your scenario).

Your best option to get `rsync` on the Windows side is to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Also remember that the Ubuntu server needs `rsync` installed as it will start a "server" instance of `rsync` on the other end of the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one time activity, you can probably use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org//).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest is to setup samba server on ubuntu.

```
#apt-get install samba
```

edit_with_editor (mcedit, vi, nano) /etc/samba.conf
add your shear
add smbuser and you ready to go, then you can access your shear from windows computer like it was another windows computer (mount net storage)